# VSE effects do not appear in final render

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-zZMiMCTYo

I have 2.79 and the tutorial appears to be using 2.8

I am new to blender. I followed it perfectly but when I render the project, it renders without the effect. I can see the effect with the view node and it even auto renders.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FxYRA-hWp-wdNptftuKMBaHHXiZkfzAs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please add an image of your render settings. are both sequencer and compositing enabled in post processing options? You may also add a sample .blend file  to your question using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you wish. This may make things easier for others to help you.

Comment: I added a link to a screen recording of it.

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.

Comment: Generally, to utilize Compositor inside VSE you have to use "Scene" strip, but this subject is entirely Compositor job and VSE is unnecessary here.

Comment: What do I do? I don't know what VSE Scene strip or anything else of what you said is. Just tell me what to do, please.